# SQL Server 2008R2 migation to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server instance running on Windows Server 2008 R2. The instance is hosting 120 databases. I want to migrate the SQL Server to a new physical server running Windows Server 2012R2 and SQL Server 2014 software installed on it.

To manually back up and restore databases is not a good option for me. How do I migrate the instance with 120 databases to SQL Server 2014?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why manual backup and restore is not a good option?  You have other options such as setting up a temporary log shipping operation, you could also setup a mirror and then do a failover, but both of those requiring applying backups first.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to upgrade all 120 databases in a single step is to upgrade the existing SQL Server instance in-place. No other way. Even if you have the databases on a SAN, the best you can do is detach from current instance then attach to new instance. Two actions per database, no shortcuts.

Backup/restore for 120 databases is a fair bit of work and depending on their sizes, it could take a long time also. However, it is pretty easy work plus the huge benefit you get is a quick and easy fallback to the original instance if something went bad with the new version. If you upgraded in place, it's a lot more effort to revert to the previous version.